# Need a type safe method of creating object

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

```
string attribute = doc.SelectSingleNode("/class/@name").Value.ToString();
ObjectHandle employee = Activator.CreateInstance("EmployeeData", attribute);
Object employeeObject = employee.Unwrap();
return employeeObject;
```

'EmployeeData' is the current executing assembly. Attribute is selected from entry node of an XML file. I need to create and return an object in a more type safe way, without using ObjectHandle and UnWrap(). Can anyone help?

Comment: And what's wrong with this approach? What's preventing you from using any other overload of `Activator.CreateInstance`? You will have to translate the full qualified name of the type to an actual type anyway, so what's the problem?

Comment: What kind of type safety do you need, if you have a string with type name as input?

Comment: @HansKesting: "EmployeeData" is the name of the assembly, not the type.

Comment: What about a factory pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this would do the job:

```
var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(attribute);
return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Using the `CreateInstance(Type)` overload guarantees that the assembly defining the type is already loaded, so that overload is free to return a straight `object`.

Comment: Also how can I get the attribute string without using 'selectSingleNode'?

Comment: Nothing. Was just exploring other possibilities.